# Scroll UITableViewCell background like Spotify/Weather app

Tags: uitableview, background, scroll, parallax

If you take a look at the iOS 7 Weather app on iPhone you will see that as you scroll, the background of the UITableViewCells scroll too(each independently of the rest). Recently, Spotify issued an iPad update that added the same feature(search for an artist on iPad, then look at their albums). I'm trying to figure out how it's done. I'm thinking it might tie in to how parallax is treated in iOS 7(motionEffects) but I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying find same feature, and i create same question with your description of trouble and i find solution, see my question - [myQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147649/cells-background-parallax-like-in-ios7-weather-app)