# Cells background parallax like in iOS7 weather app

Tags: ios, uitableview

If you take a look at the iOS 7 Weather app on iPhone you will see that as you scroll, the background of the UITableViewCells scroll too(each independently of the rest). I'm trying to figure out how it's done. Any ideas?

---

**Answer is**

```
-(void)scrollTable:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float offset = _tableViewNew.contentOffset.y / _tableViewNew.frame.size.height;
    for (int i = 0; i <[cellTitle count]; i++) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableViewNew cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(cell.backgroundView.frame.origin.x, offset * 50, cell.backgroundView.frame.size.width, cell.backgroundView.frame.size.height);
        cell.backgroundView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call that a parallax effect. All it does is to set the starting position of all the cell backgrounds relative to the scroll position. Say your cell background images are 150 units high and your total scrollable height is 400 units.

The scrolled percentage is then:

```
relative scroll offset = tableView.contentOffset.Y / 400.
```

Whenever the table view scrolls (you get that by implementing `UIScrollViewDelegate's` `scrollViewDidScroll:)`, adjust the vertical position of your cell backgrounds:

```
cell background offset = relative scroll offset * 150
```

In order to implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` you need to set the `UITableView's` property delegate. As `UITableView` subclasses `UIScrollView`, this property expected a [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) instance. In your controller, implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` and set the delegate property to your controller.

Comment: Nice, but how i can get cell in "scrollViewDidScroll:" and set background offset?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! You gave a good idea! I have worked out! =) Worked code posted in answer comments! =)